# How to combine two queries without making it an AND type query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 5.0 app.
In this app I want to create a query that get all users with active subscriptions and then merge them with a query that get all users that are admins. I try to do it but the new query make them one long query where all criterias needs to be a match. This is not what I want.

*Like it is now only admins will be found. I want to find all matching user AND then just merge in the admins. Do I perhaps need to run both FULL queries and THEN merge them?*

I want to run the first query and then the second query and then just merge them.

```
def self.with_active_subscription_and_admins
  active = User.with_active_subscription
  admins = User.admins
  active.merge(admins)
end
```

The actual query that is run

```
SELECT  "users".*
FROM "users"
INNER JOIN "subscriptions" ON "subscriptions"."user_id" = "users"."id"
WHERE "subscriptions"."is_active" = true
AND "users"."is_admin" = true
AND (size_min <= 100 AND rooms_min <= 200 AND price_max >= 300)
LIMIT 11
```

I cannot use this type of merge since it results in an array

```
def self.with_active_subscription_and_admins
  User.with_active_subscription + User.admins
end
```

This is the final query (how it is used) and that won´t work if the above output is an array

```
users = User.with_active_subscription_and_admins.where("size_min <= ? AND rooms_min <= ? AND price_max >= ?", size, rooms, price)
```

The scope used in User is

```
scope :with_active_subscription, lambda {
  joins(:subscription).where(subscriptions: { is_active: true })
}
```

I also tried this but then I get copies in array. Can I do it distinct and is this a bad query?

```
users = User.with_active_subscription.where("size_min <= ? AND rooms_min <= ? AND price_max >= ?", 100, 200, 300)
admins = User.admins.where("size_min <= ? AND rooms_min <= ? AND price_max >= ?", 100, 200, 300)
records = users + admins
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To merge arrays of objects together in Ruby (and Rails) you can use the `|` symbol like so:

```rb
def self.with_active_subscription_and_admins
  active = User.with_active_subscription #=> [#<User id: 1 ...>, ...]
  admins = User.admins #=> [#<User id: 5 ...>, ...]
  admins | active #=> [#<User id: 1 ...>, #<User id: 5 ...>, ...]
end
```

So that your `with_active_subscription_and_admins` method returns the merged arrays.